# Cannot render datatable in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have question about rendering `datatable` in shiny.

Here is my sample code:

```
head(pm)
  product previous current      rate
1       a        0       2   2.00000
2       b       12      28 133.33333
3       c       22      76 245.45455
4       d       26      52 100.00000
5       e       18      24  33.33333
6       f       32      92 187.50000
```

And my shiny codes are:

```
##ignoring some other codes
## in server.R
library(shiny)
library(DT)
output$matrix <- renderDataTable(DT::datatable(pm, options = list(searching = TRUE,
                                                                               pageLength = 10,
                                                                               lengthMenu = c(10, 50, 100))))
## in ui.R, ignoring main page stuff
tabPanel("matrix testing",
                 DT::dataTableOutput("matrix"))
```

These codes are modified as suggested from some other SO posts. However when I run shiny, it returns:

[image]

I run out of solutions and have no idea how to deal with it. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your little info, this works:

```
pm <- read.table(header=T,text="
  product previous current      rate
1       a        0       2   2.00000
2       b       12      28 133.33333
3       c       22      76 245.45455
4       d       26      52 100.00000
5       e       18      24  33.33333
6       f       32      92 187.50000")
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$matrix <- renderDataTable(DT::datatable(pm, options = list(searching = TRUE,
                                                                               pageLength = 10,
                                                                               lengthMenu = c(10, 50, 100))))
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("matrix testing", dataTableOutput("matrix"))))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Still not working :( Any additional info I can update?

Comment: @BigD: Oops, a `}` was missing. Update packages? Provide a reproducible example instead a stump?